# P5 canvas width or height is offset

Tags: canvas, p5.js

I want to place a text(and some other things) in a P5js Canvas. I passed the coordinates 50, 50 but the text is misplaced, as you can see with the colored bars.

[image]

Another instance is when I want to translate the screen to center a specific rectangle, when trying to use the canvas width to follow it after it passed a certain point.

My canvas width is 1000.

My centering works fine when using 450 in my calculation, but when I use width/2 it does not work.

How can I get P5js to display my canvas accordingly, or what is the problem in general?

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 700);
}

function draw() {
  // Some other stuff

  textSize(32);
  fill(255);
  text("Some Text", 50, 50);

  // Some other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/text):

By default, the coordinate you pass into the `text()` function specifies the lower-left corner of the text.

> If `x2` and `y2` are not specified, the baseline alignment is the default, which means that the text will be drawn upwards from `x` and `y`.

You have a few options:

- Take the height of the string into account when calculating where to draw it. There are some handy functions in the **typography** section of [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/) that can help you do this.
- Use the 4-argument version of the `text()` function to pass in a bounding rectangle.
- Use the `textAlign()` function to specify how your text should display. Again, [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/textAlign) is your friend.